# “zip_read() expects parameter 1 to be resource, integer given”

Tags: php

When trying to execute the following snippet

```
zip_open($full_file_path);
```

The script returns "zip_read() expects parameter 1 to be resource, integer given"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

1) Double check your path and file permissions

2) Make sure ZIP is valid (sometimes happens with 3rd party generated archives)

3) Echo out the integer returned by the zip function and lookup the code online

Answer (score 1):

Try this, if You are not able to read file through `zip_open()`

Firstly ensure that you have read/write permission to your file also ensure that `zip/bzip2` extensions are enabled

If file opens, it returns resource else integer value
Also check that you are passing full path to `zip_open()`

```
$zip = zip_open("/assets/test.zip");
//or full path
$zip = zip_open("D:\\Server\\xampp\\htdocs\\test.zip");
```

because sometimes it can't recognize `'./'`
So try to pass full path of your file.